# Symfony 2 image loading issue

Tags: php, css, image, symfony, web

When I tried to install the project in my localhost, images are not loading. The below image will show my issue. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?? Thanks.

[image]

**Update**

My image link is as follows

```
<img src="/images/my_image/{{ image }}" />
```

I tried a lot but couldn't able to solve this problem.

Comment: If you open up your browsers developer tools, what appears in the network tab? Is it a bunch of red names.  It looks like you don't have the images or the link is point in the wrong location

Comment: Check the URLs of the images if they're correct and URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please check using right click you can inspect this element and check existence path of image.

because image path could not be find. please check image path and try to open in new tan url and check path.

or may be file and folder permission issue it is rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

Like others stated, check the the developers tools in the web browser check the links, it is probably to do with the assets install, do you have a public folder under Resources? if so try and see if you have something like

```
src="{{ asset('bundles/login/assets/images/logo.jpg') }}
```

inside your img tags, if so edit that and see if it works
usually the web/bundles/ directory is gitignored, if that is the case then you just need to run `php app/console assets:install --symlink` if you are using symfony 2.6, if you not using that version and you get an error then run the above command without the --symlink . symlink is preferred way as any changes you make will be reflected in the web root directory